# How to plot a rectangle facing in a particuliar direction in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot a rectangle centered at the position `(x, y, z)`, with length `a` along the `(n1x, n1y, n1z)` direction and width `b` along the `(n2x, n2y, n2z)` direction. I also want the surface of the rectangle to face a certain direction, the direction being specified by a unit vector perpendicular to the face of the rectangle `(nx, ny, nz`).

How do I create a function that takes in `(x, y, z)`, `a`, `b`, and `(nx, ny, nz)` which plots a rectangle using matplotlib?

Comment: For the normal vector `(nx, ny, nz)`, would you expect the same output if you used `(-1,0,0)` as `(1,0,0)`? Aka do you want the two sides of the rectangle to be distinguishable? Also, as described, the rectangle can have any rotational position about the normal vector. Do you want more specific control than that over its rotational position or are you okay with that?

Comment: @TimH Ideally each side should have different colors. I guess I will also specify two other vectors n1 and n2 which define the sides of the rectangle.

Comment: @gboffi I edited the question to specify that the length `a` and width `b` should be along directions defined by two other vectors.

Comment: if you know the versors parallel to rectangle's sides, the normal versor is then unnecessary, and you can compute the four vertices of the rectangle simply as `P = (x₀, y₀, z₀) ± n₁·a/2 ± n₂·b/2`

Answer (score 0):

#### This answer is wrong! See comments.

<s>The equation of a plane with normal vector `(a, b, c)` passing through `(0, 0, 0)` is `ax + by + cz = 0`. From this equation we can get the explicit formula `z = -(a/c)x - (b/c)y` to calculate the height of the plane at each planar point `(x, y)`. We can set up the X, Y, Z matrices using `numpy.meshgrid` and the previous formula.</s>

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plane(cx, cy, cz, nx, ny, nz, length, width):
    x = np.linspace(-length/2, length/2)
    y = np.linspace(-width/2, width/2)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = -(nx/nz)*X - (ny/nz)*Y
    X += cx
    Y += cy
    Z += cz
    return X, Y, Z

# coordinates of the center point
cx, cy, cz = 3, 6, 9
# components of the normal vector
nx, ny, nz = 1, 1, 1
# dimensions of the rectangle
length, width = 4, 5

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = plane(cx, cy, cz, nx, ny, nz, length, width)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

**UPDATE:** (including the center point in the calculations instead of deferring translations to the end)

The equation of a plane with normal vector `(a, b, c)` passing through `(x0, y0, z0)` is `ax + by + cz = ax0 + by0 + c*z0`. From this equation we can get the explicit formula `z = (ax0 + by0 + cz0)/c - (a/c)x - (b/c)y` to calculate the height of the plane at each planar point `(x, y)`. We can set up the X, Y, Z matrices using `numpy.meshgrid` and the previous formula.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plane(cx, cy, cz, nx, ny, nz, length, width):
    x = np.linspace(cx - length/2, cx + length/2)
    y = np.linspace(cy - width/2, cy + width/2)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = (nx*cx + ny*cy + nz*cz)/nz - (nx/nz)*X - (ny/nz)*Y
    return X, Y, Z

# coordinates of the center point
cx, cy, cz = 3, 6, 9
# components of the normal vector
nx, ny, nz = 1, 1, 1
# dimensions of the rectangle
length, width = 4, 5

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = plane(cx, cy, cz, nx, ny, nz, length, width)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What if I want my normal to point in either the x, y, or z direction, e.g. `(1,0,0)`. This would give a divide by 0 error.

Comment: Also, if I have not misunderstood your implementation, the sides of the rectangle aren't actually `length` and `width`, but the projection of the rectangle onto the xy plane has those dimensions.

Comment: Indeed, now that you mention it the length and width do not belong to the rectangle. I also noticed that this code generates a cross section of a rectangular prism, which is not necessarily a rectangle at all. I don't know how to approach this problem then, guess I'll strikethrough my answer.